# (Azure) az batch pool : error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Unable to create batch pool:

```
> az login 
> az account set --subscription $myid
> az batch account set --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $batchAccountName
> az batch pool create --json-file pool.json

usage: az batch pool create [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
                            [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml,none}]
                            [--query JMESPATH] [--id ID] [--vm-size VM_SIZE]
                            [--os-family {2,3,4,5}] [--os-version OS_VERSION]
                            [--node-agent-sku-id NODE_AGENT_SKU_ID]
                            [--resize-timeout RESIZE_TIMEOUT]
                            [--target-dedicated-nodes TARGET_DEDICATED_NODES]
                            [--target-low-priority-nodes TARGET_LOW_PRIORITY_NODES]
                            [--auto-scale-formula AUTO_SCALE_FORMULA]
                            [--enable-inter-node-communication]
                            [--start-task-command-line START_TASK_COMMAND_LINE]
                            [--start-task-resource-files START_TASK_RESOURCE_FILES [START_TASK_RESOURCE_FILES ...]]
                            [--start-task-wait-for-success]
                            [--certificate-references CERTIFICATE_REFERENCES [CERTIFICATE_REFERENCES ...]]
                            [--application-package-references APPLICATION_PACKAGE_REFERENCES [APPLICATION_PACKAGE_REFERENCES ...]]
                            [--application-licenses APPLICATION_LICENSES [APPLICATION_LICENSES ...]]
                            [--max-tasks-per-node MAX_TASKS_PER_NODE]
                            [--metadata METADATA [METADATA ...]]
                            [--json-file JSON_FILE]
                            [--account-name ACCOUNT_NAME]
                            [--account-key ACCOUNT_KEY]
                            [--account-endpoint ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT]
                            [--image IMAGE] [--subscription _SUBSCRIPTION]
az batch pool create: error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Content of pool.json:
[Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/batch/pool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-batch-pool-create)

[image]

I just noticed I am getting the same error with other batch pool commands:

```
C:\Users\>az batch pool list
usage: az batch pool list [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
                          [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml,none}]
                          [--query JMESPATH] [--filter FILTER]
                          [--select SELECT] [--expand EXPAND]
                          [--account-name ACCOUNT_NAME]
                          [--account-key ACCOUNT_KEY]
                          [--account-endpoint ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT]
                          [--subscription _SUBSCRIPTION]
az batch pool list: error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I have reinstalled azure cli again but no difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your issue, I can reappear the same error as you:

[image]

That is because you need to log in with the Batch account, not only log in with Azure CLI.

[image]

You can see the description in [Manage Batch resources with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-cli-get-started), it shows this:

> To use the Azure CLI with Batch, you need to log in and authenticate.
>   There are two simple steps to follow:
>
> 1. Log into Azure. Logging into Azure gives you access to Azure Resource Manager commands, including Batch Management service
>      commands.
> 2. Log into your Batch account. Logging into your Batch account gives you access to Batch service commands.

So I think the possible reason is that you also need to log in the Batch account.